# how can i pass value in rxjs subscribe function?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm working on switching the code to rxjs

here is my original code.

```
userAuth$: BehaviorSubject<ArticleInfoRes>;

  async loadArticleList(articleId: number) {
    try {
      const data = await this.articleApi.loadArticleList(articleId);
      this.userAuth$.next(data);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
```

Subsequently, an attempt was made to convert to rxjs, but the value was not delivered properly. A value or error must be passed to the location where the loadArticleList function is used. Please tell me what's wrong

This is the code I tried to convert.

```
userAuth$: BehaviorSubject<ArticleInfoRes>;

loadArticleList(articleId: number) {
  from(this.articleApi.loadArticleList(articleId)).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.userAuth$.next(data);
      return data;
    },
    error => {
      return error;
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: What exactly is incorrect, is the data null or undefined? If so try doing your subscription like so: .pipe(takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)).subscribe(....) where componentDestroyed$ is defined as componentDestroyed$ = new Subject<void>();. Make sure your loadArticleList method also returns an observable

Comment: `A value or error must be passed to the location where the loadArticleList function is used.` Is that code expecting a promise still? Or an observable?

Comment: return undefined @SomeStudent

Comment: expection observable @NicholasTower

Comment: The signature for the `next`  and `error` functions are `(value: T) => void` and `(error: any) => void` respectively.  So those return statements shouldn't be there.  But not sure that would break anything.  What is the calling code expecting in return?  The original function was returning a promise, and you're not returning anything here.

Comment: this looks a lot like antipattern

Comment: @sjfklsaf the reason why `loadArticleList` returns `undefined` is because you're missing a `return` statement in said method. Regarless, your code still won't work, detailed in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72335072/7931817.

Answer (score 0):

> A value or error must be passed to the location where the loadArticleList function is used. Please tell me what's wrong

To answer your question directly, the reason why the result (i.e., value or error) isn't passed to where you use `loadArticleList()` is because your RxJS pipeline is not built properly. For one, adding `return data;` and `return error;` in your subscription handlers won't actually return `data` nor `error`.

To get the result, you might want to "trickle down" (streamline) that result further down the RxJS pipeline, so that subscription to that result happens in the location you speak of, to where `loadArticleList()` is used. This translates to moving your call to `.subscribe()` **outside** of `loadArticleList()`, not inside.

So, here's a proper RxJS revision:

```ts
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";

userAuth$: BehaviorSubject<ArticleInfoRes>;

loadArticleList(articleId: number) {
  return from(this.articleApi.loadArticleList(articleId)).pipe(
    tap((data) => this.userAuth$.next(data)) //  tap into the result to update the next userAuth$
  );
}
```

Using the `tap` RxJS operator, we can grab the result of `loadAarticleList(articleId)`, process it according to your callback function inside `tap` (in this case, simply update the next value of `userAuth$`), and then with that same grabbed result, unmodified, pass it on to whoever subscribes to `loadArticleList()`.

Finally, to actually "pass" `data` or `error`to the location where the `loadArticleList` function is used, simply subscribe there.

```ts
// in your component's .ts somwehere, probably
loadArticleList(123).subscribe(
  data  => { /* do as you want with the result     */ },
  error => { /* add your error-handling logic here */ }
);
```